# CallContext change from WPF menu

Tags: wpf, .net-remoting

Has anyone tried changing content of the CallContext from a WPF menu?
In our app we have an environment string stored in callcontext - on the server it is converted to a db connectionstring (using ILogicalThreadAffinative + .net remoting).

On the client it is possible to switch between environments, when changed the new threads/windows have the new environment - all windows have environment in the window title.

The problem is that when this is done from a MenuItem it seems that WPF pushes the CallContext on some stack and pops it back afterwards making it impossible to change.

I have solved it by inserting a combobox in the menu - that seems to work but is not so nice.
Has anybody seen this and found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I think this happens because a mouse click on a menu item will cause a new operation to be posted to the dispatcher queue and CallContext is not persisted between operations in the dispatcher queue.

See [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/8214a86a-1081-4690-a387-3b5bacbeb1cf/) for more info.

Comment: I think you are right - I have also looked into the execution context. I just find it inconsistent that I can change callcontext from a button in a window and from a combobox in a menu, but not as a selection in a submenu. I think this use of callcontext is what it was intended for - so I am wondering if it is a bug?

Comment: I tried a small sample and my callcontext is being reset for both buttons, comboboxes and menus.  So the callcontext is always empty for me which of course is more consistent than what you are seeing.

Comment: I will look into it again and see what I can come up with - if you can't change the callcontext from wpf it sort of takes out some of its use. My example have set callcontext from the start and it is when I try to change it the trouble occurs.